# How can I select nth child of an nth child using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

How could I do either of these in jquery?

1. nth Child of nth child
2. first child of nth child
3. descendants (children OR grandchildren) of nth child which are images

Edit: I am using a variable to access the 'child' like this

```
var number = ( ... code ...) ;
.... eq(number)
```

so I cant do anything like

```
$('li:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

combine the two?

```
//1
$(":nth-child(2) :nth-child(3)")
//2
$(":nth-child(2) :first-child")
//3
$(":nth-child(2) img")
```

Do it the same way you would in a css stylesheet.

```
var number = 2;
//1
$(":nth-child(" + number + ") :nth-child(" + number + ")")
//2
$(":nth-child(" + number + ") :first-child")
//3
$(":nth-child(" + number + ") img")
```

Comment: thanks sorry I forgot to mention in my question that the nth was coming from a variable necessitating the other way of doing eq(). I have revised my question

Comment: so `number` is a variable that contains the child number? your question is unclear now.

Comment: you can still use the same selector, `":nth-child(" + number + ")...`

Comment: why are you using `:inth-child`, will `:nth-child` not work there?

Comment: so strange because I looked it up and found this ... http://imstillreallybored.com/2012/why-you-shouldnt-use-inth-child-yet/

Comment: I think that's a typo too, that selector doesn't exist.

Comment: Yea it's not on the jquery website anyway. Weird thing is he does it twice.